# Showing search results using ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Hi I'm working on a simple asp.net mvc application. 
I have a search button that returns a table of Products .
I put this table in a partial view. When I click on search button it opens another page, what I really want is top show the search result(table)on the same page.
Here's the the search method in Home Controller

```
      public ActionResult SearchM(string Search)
    {
        var viewMod = new MyViewModel
        {
            ProductsV = DB.Products.Where(x => 
      x.ProductName.StartsWith(Search)).ToList()

        };
        return View(viewMod);
    }
    }
```

Products Partial View

```
 @model OnlineShopping.MyViewModel

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>


 <table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>

        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Product Image</th>

    </tr>
</thead>
@foreach (Product item in Model.ProductsV)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.ProductName</td>
        <td>@item.ProductPrice</td>
        <td>@item.ProductDetails</td>
        <td><img src="@Url.Content(@item.ProductImage)" width="120" 
   height="160" /></td>
    </tr>

  }
 </table>
```

Index View

```
   <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#SearchMenu').click(function () {
                $('.showSearch').toggle("slide");
            });
        });
  </script>

 <h3>Search:</h3>


 @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchM", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{

    <label> Search:</label> <input type="text" name="Search" class="btn- 
  block" />
    <br />

    <div id="SearchMenu">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn-light" />

    </div>

  }


  <div id="showSearch"><input type="button" class="btn-success" 
   value="Show/Hide All Products" /></div><br />
  <div class="SearchMenu" style="display: none;">
    @Html.Partial("SearchM", Model)
  </div>
```

Comment: I don't see you're using `$.ajax()` anywhere. Also that your button has `<input type="submit" ... />`, this causes postback and reloads the page. You can look at [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520377/asp-net-mvc-how-to-page-ajax-search-results) and [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32783526/how-to-search-using-ajax-in-asp-net-mvc) to get started with AJAX call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the MVC AJAX helper or intercept the submit event with an AJAX call.

As you're using MVC, I will suggest that you use the AJAX helper.

You'll need to install Microsoft.Jquery.Unobtrusive.Ajax from the NuGet Package Manager in order to use the helper.

Once you have that installed, it should be as simple as changing this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchM", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
```

To this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchM", "Home", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "SearchMenu" }))
```

Comment: Thank you mate, I'll be working on it and will keep you updated

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. :) Please consider marking my answer if it has satisfied your question.